# Why is the page execution time so much slower in Symfony 2.1 than 2.0

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I've updated from 2.0 to 2.1 When testing using the `app_dev.php` with the profiler on the same page I get two very diverse results:

Symfony 2.0

- execution time: 799ms
- memory used: 6144 kb

[image]

Symfony 2.1

- execution time: 2070ms
- memory used: 18.5 MB

[image]

It happens on all pages, that the loading time is 1-2 seconds slower and the memory usage is very high. I also cleared the cache and reloaded the page at least two times.

On both pages the settings are the same:

- PHP version: 5.3.6
- Xdebug: disabled
- PHP acceleration: enabled
- XCache: enabled
- APC: disabled
- EAccelerator: disabled

Am I missing something here or why is this happening?

Comment: Actually, the profiler was completly redone. It could be that in dev/test environment it is slower due to more in depth profiler. Could you check with the prod environment (using chrome developer tools or firebug)?

Comment: @Sgoettschkes I've tested it and still, the one using 2.1 is about 1 sec slower even in production.

Comment: @elnur You mean like *forwarding*? I do, but not on the tested pages.

Comment: I wonder about the same thing...

Comment: Even if you try the demo login page, 2.0 is almost 2 times faster than 2.1. But I have only tested with the debug bar loaded, so as Sgoettschkes said, in this case it may simply be the new profiler.

Comment: I didn't have this problem at all, try enabling APC, it's quite relevant in production.

Comment: My memory consumption and rendering times are actually faster since using Symfony 2.1... Without any sample code I don't think that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I see that 3 requests are run on your Symfony 2.0 app, and only 2 on your Symfony 2.1 app. Are you sure you're testing the same page? Can you compare the executed queries?
An other thing: Symfony 2.1 seems to tell you that some Entities are now valid (just click on the red balloon on the right of the 18.5 MB memory consumption)

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin That's right. You're the first one seeing this. But it's as simple as this: Symfony 2.0 shows the setting of the default character set (UTF-8) as an extra query, so it's 3 instead of 2. :) And the red icon in Symfony 2.1 tells that the user is not authenticated.